# Target class [FrontendController] does not exist

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

please help. I got this error "Target class [FrontendController] does not exist."

This is my route :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/','FrontendController@home');
```

My Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class FrontendController extends Controller
{
      public function home()
    {
       return view ('index');
    }
}
```

Why this happend? can anyone help me please? :(

Comment: What version of Laravel you use?

Answer (score 1):

You have to refer to the controller, you have 2 options

Laravel 7 and lower

```
Route::get('/','App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@home');
```

If you are using Laravel 8 then you have to change the structure of the route

```
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController::class, 'home']);
```